# Stream broadcast image through socket.io-stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, stream, socket.io

Right now I have code, that sends image or any other file from the browser to the server, the server then broadcasts the stream to all other sockets. It all works fine, but the part I have no clue in how to implement is the receiving end of the browser.

Browser send:

```
var file = files[0]
var stream = ss.createStream()
ss(socket).emit('file', stream, { size: file.size })
ss.createBlobReadStream(file).pipe(stream)
```

Server:

```
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.jpg'))

  var newStream = ss.createStream()

  ss(socket).emit('file', newStream)
  stream.pipe(newStream)
})
```

Browser Receive:

```
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
  // Implement this
})
```

I'm not exactly sure what to do with the incoming stream and use the image I just sent, display it or any other task. I appreciate any help you can give to me about this, or point to anything wrong in this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a uint8array by listening for data events on the browser receive.  I still don't know what to do then though.

```
ss(socket).on('file', function(stream, data) {
  stream.on("data",function(uint8array){ //do something })
})
```

The other events I would expect to see don't seem to show up in the client received stream.